# SystemVerilog: S-R Latch doesn't work correctly

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, flipflop, latch, system-verilog

Here is my gate level description of an S-R latch:

```
module SR_Latch_Nand(input S, R, C, output Q, QB);
wire s1, r1;
nand #8 n1(r1, R, C);
nand #8 n2(s1, S, C);
nand #8 n3(QB, R, Q);
nand #8 n4(Q, S, QB);
endmodule
```

and here is testbench for this S-R latch:

```
module SR_Latch_Nand_TB();
logic s, r, clk;
wire q, qb;
SR_Latch_Nand sr(s, r, clk, q, qb);
initial begin
  s = 0; r = 0; clk = 0;
  #100 s = 1;
  #100 clk = 1;
  #100 clk = 0;
  #100 clk = 1;
  #100 s = 0;
  #100;
end
endmodule
```

When I check the waveform, the value of `Q` is x at most of the times. Other times, it's mostly incorrect. I've tried to preset values of `q` and `qb`, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Can you tell what's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your testbench and the way you set r and s. If they are both active low, then make sure your testbench tests only one active low.

Answer (score -1):

The code of SR_Latch_Nand is wrong.
You missed to use the s1 and r1 for the output flops.
Corrected SR latch module should be.

```
module SR_Latch_Nand(input S, R, C, output Q, QB);
  wire s1, r1;
  nand #8 n1(r1, R, C);
  nand #8 n2(s1, S, C);
  nand #8 n3(QB, s1, Q);
  nand #8 n4(Q, r1, QB);
endmodule
```

Comment: This does not improve this simulation results.  The `n1` and`n2` instances (and the `C` input) in the question are unnecessary.